# is md5 encryption still strong for usage to encrypt admin password

Tags: php, password-encryption

I want to encrypt the admin/members passwords, but I don't know if the MD5 is still strong for that, or became weak.
And what is the strong alternatives for encrypting the passwords like MD5 in the past.

Comment: No, it is not. Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) with BCRYPT.

Comment: MD5 isn't encryption, it's hashing. And no it is not strong enough. It was *never* strong enough.